# de or du - what is the correct answer

Tags: usage

Dans ce restaurant on sert _____ bon thé. Do we write du or de in the blank. When an adjective precceds the noun in plural we use de instead of des. Ex : Il y a de nouveaux livres. Does this rule apply for singular too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both. The rule you cite is correct. But your sentence should be a plural:

```
Dans ce restaurant, on sert de bons thés.
```

=> they have good teas.
But you can also say :

```
Dans ce restaurant, on sert du bon thé.
```

In that case, you just refer to tea in general : they have some good tea.